# .NET Core 2 - Copying folder to

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider

I currently have a folder names "templates" which contain a set of JSON file that I would like being copied in the build process. (eg. bin/Debug/../templates/)

Using a .NET Core 2 Console App, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be fixed in 2018.1. We are preparing for EAP program for 2018.1 right now =) 
For more details see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-9684

Answer (score 4):

If the folder is inside your project file's directory, add this `Update` item statement to the csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="templates\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If they are outside your project directory add them using an `Include` item statement with the `LinkBase` metadata to specify the target subdirectory:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\templates\**" LinkBase="templates" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score -2):

go to project properties on build events tab add where it says prebuild events or post-build events depending on your need add a command, same as you would in regular windows cmd. You can also use relative paths.

Comment: Do you have any example out of the effet on .csproj? Can't find those option in Jetbrains Rider.

Comment: pre/postbuild steps with command lines should be avoided if possible to ensure working incremental builds and being able to build cross-platform. e.g. on Mac/linux there would be no `xcopy`